# Want to remove numbers from pandas dataframe and implement CountVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a data in the following form:

```
    author  text
0   garyvee     A lot of people misunderstand Gary’s message o...
1   jasonfried  "I can’t remember having a goal. An actual goa...
2   biz         "Tools that can create media that looks and so...
```

I tried the following to clean the text:

```
text_data.loc[:,"text"] = text_data.text.apply(lambda x : str.lower(x))
text_data.loc[:,"text"] = text_data.text.apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.findall('[\w]+',x)))
```

I got output but it contains digits I dont want that for the Text Analysis

```
0    a lot of people misunderstand gary s message o...
1    i can t remember having a goal an actual goal ...
2    tools that can create media that looks and sou...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

but while removing numbers in the text string:

```
text_data.loc[:,"text"] = text_data.text.apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.sub('^[0-9\.]*$','',x)))
```

I got the output:

```
0    a l o t o f p e o p l e m i s u n d e r s t a ...
1    i c a n t r e m e m b e r h a v i n g a g o a ...
2    t o o l s t h a t c a n c r e a t e m e d i a ...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

How to avoid it? How to implement CountVectorizer?

Comment: why are you using `" ".join` ?

Comment: removed but still there are numbers in the text data, but now all words are discrete.

Comment: Is your regex correct? Check manually whether your regex is correct or not.

Comment: '000', '100', '12', '16', '1st', '20', '200', '20s', '2nd', '30s', '3rd', '50', '5000', '503c', '52', '57', 'a12zracs8z', how to remove these kind of words?

Comment: oh figured out np

Comment: You can improve this question by adding the self answer to your question. How you fixed it.

Comment: Post your own answer about how you solved it to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did mistake at this stage:

```
text_data.loc[:,"text"] = text_data.text.apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.sub('^[0-9\.]*$','',x)))
```

It should be

```
text_data.loc[:,"text"] = text_data.text.apply(lambda x : re.sub('^[0-9\.]*$','',x))
```